# Can't download files, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop' with telepot

Tags: python, telegram, telepot

i'm trying to download some files with a telegram bot using telepot, but when I try to download it, it gives me this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop'
```

This is the current code:

```
def on_chat_message(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    file_id = msg['document']['file_id']
    bot.download_file(file_id,os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to save a file named `C:\Users\***\Desktop`.  You can't do that because `C:\Users\***\Desktop` is a directory.

On Windows, you will get a permission-denied error attempting to open a directory for reading or writing as if it were a file.

You will have to specify the name of the file somehow.  It may be in the `msg` object you receive, I don't know.

Instead of writing

```py
    bot.download_file(file_id,os.getcwd())
```

try

```py
    file_name = "somefilenamehere.txt" # or look up from msg
    bot.download_file(file_id, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name))
```